# Can this system of coupled ODEs be solved by shooting method?

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I met a system of coulped ODEs like:
\begin{eqnarray}
m'(r)&=&g(r)+\frac{1}{2} r^2 f(r) \phi '(r)^2+\frac{1}{2} \gamma ^2 r^2 \phi(r)^2;\\
\phi ''(r)&=&\frac{2 \alpha g(r) }{rf(r)}+\frac{\gamma ^2 \phi (r)}{f(r)} +\frac{\phi '(r) }{f(r)}\left(\frac{2 g(r)}{r}+\frac{f(r)-1}{r}+\gamma ^2 r \phi(r)^2\right)-\frac{2 \phi '(r)}{r}.
\end{eqnarray}
Here the function $f(r)=1-\frac{2m(r)}{r}$ and $g(r)=\left(\sqrt{\text{Q}^2+r^4}-r^2\right) \exp (2 \alpha  \phi (r))$. And
$\alpha, Q, \gamma$ are all constants. We also know the boundary conditions:$\phi(\infty)=0, m(\infty)=M$. At a priori unknown point $r0$ between $(0,\infty)$, there are $f(r0)=0$ and $f'(\text{r0}) \phi '(\text{r0})=\frac{2 \alpha g(r0)}{\text{r0}}+\gamma ^2 \phi (\text{r0})$.

Obviously, this is a kind of BVP with two boundaries at $r=r0$ and $r=\infty$. The parameter $M$ can be treated as an input parameter,and $r0$ is a priori unknown and should be determined additionally.

I want to use the shooting method and I write a Mathematica code for this problem

```
rs = 10^-4; rm = 100; alp = -1; Q = 1; gam = 1; M=1;
f[r_] := 1 - 2 m[r]/r;
g[r_]:=(Sqrt[Q^2+r^4]-r^2)*Exp[2*alp*Phi[r]];
eq1=m'[r] == 1/2*f[r]*r^2*(Phi'[r])^2 + 1/2*gam^2*r^2*Phi[r]^2 + g[r];
eq2=Phi''[r] == -2 Phi'[r]/r + f[r]^(-1)*((f[r] - 1)/r + gam^2*Phi[r]^2*r + 2g[r]/r)*Phi'[r] + f[r]^(-1)*(gam^2*Phi[r] + 2 alp*g[r]/r);
```

Then,I write $m(r), \phi(r)$ in series form:

```
n = 6;mseries = Sum[a[i] r^-i, {i, 0, n}];phiseries = Sum[b[i] r^-i, {i, 1, n}](*output is a[0] + a[1]/r + a[2]/r^2 + a[3]/r^3 + a[4]/r^4 + a[5]/r^5 + a[6]/r^6 and b[1]/r + b[2]/r^2 + b[3]/r^3 + b[4]/r^4 + b[5]/r^5 + b[6]/r^6*)
```

Next, I substitute them into the ODEs:

```
serieseqs=Simplify[Series[Unevaluated[{D[m[r],r] - (1/2*f[r]*r^2*(D[Phi[r], r])^2 + gam^2*r^2*Phi[r]^2/2 +g[r]), -D[D[Phi[r], r], r] - 2/r D[\[Phi][r], r] + f[r]^(-1)*((f[r] - 1)/r + gam^2*r*Phi[r]^2 + (2 g[r])/r)*D[Phi[r], r] + f[r]^(-1)*(gam^2*Phi[r] + 2 alp*g[r]/r)}] //. {m[r] -> mseries, Phi[r] -> phiseries}, {r, Infinity, n}]]
```

Now, one can solve the coefficients:

```
eqscoeff =Join[Table[SeriesCoefficient[serieseqs[[1]], {r, Infinity, i}] ==0, {i, 0, n}], Table[SeriesCoefficient[serieseqs[[2]], {r, Infinity, i}] == 0, {i, 1, n}]] // Simplify; 
Coeff = Solve[eqscoeff, Join[Array[a, n], Array[b, n]]]
```

In this way, I can obtain

```
mtest = mseries /. Coeff[[1]]
output:(*-(83/(40 r^5)) + 1/(4 r^4) - 1/(6 r^3) - 1/(2 r) + a[0] + a[6]/r^6*)
phitest = phiseries /. Coeff[[1]]
 output: (* 6/r^5 + 1/r^3 - (2 (1 + 9 a[0]))/r^6 *)
```

I set $a[0]=M$, so only one unknown parameter $a[6]$ left. One should determine the $a[6]$ and $r0$ together according to the boundary conditions at $r0$. Thus, I first derive the boundary conditions at $rm$:

```
newbclist = {m[rm] == mtest, Phi[rm] ==phitest, Phi'[rm] == D[phitest,r]} /. {r -> rm, a[0] -> M};
solphi = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq1, eq2, newbclist}, Phi, {r, rs, rm}, {a[6]}];
solm = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq1, eq2, newbclist}, m, {r, rs, rm}, {a[6]}];
```

I think one should solve the two boundary conditions at $r0$ like this:

```
NSolve[{m[r]==r/2/.m->solm[a[6]],f'[r]*Phi'[r]==2*alp*g[r]/r+gam^2*Phi[r]/.{m->solm[a[6]],Phi->solphi[[a[6]]}},{r,a[6]}]
```

However, I cannot get a solution!! Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please do not use `Gamma` it is a protected function in *Mathematica*.

Comment: I would recommend you do two things, first don't work with `ParametricNDSolve` until first demonstrating you can get a solution for some particular values of the parameters with `NDSolve`. Second don't mess with the shooting method until you first show your system can be robustly solved using some specified initial values.

Comment: in your math statement there are *no* conditions at zero (or "rm"), yet you have conditions there in the mathematica expression. When you say "at some `r0`" does that mean `r0` is an unknown? Please clarify..

Comment: one other observation, `delta` seems to appear only in the one equation. You can drop that equation and `delta` from the system and get `delta` after solving the rest of it.

Comment: @george2079, Thanks for your suggestion. I delete the equation on `delta` and the corresponding boundary condition. However,  using `NDSolve` we still cannot find a solution. `r0` is a priori unknown. I have assigned a value to `r0`.